# Android - React Native file upload - unexpected end of stream, broken pipe

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob, react-native-blob-util

I have a react-native app. The app uploads files using `rn-fetch-blob`.
This has worked previously with no issue.
I am attempting to upgrade RN (to version 0.66.5) as the project was a little behind this.
iOS is working fine but on Android whenever I attempt to upload a file I get the error:

`unexpected end of stream` / `broken pipe`

The problem seems to stem from `okhttp3` which is used within the `rn-fetch-blob` package.

I have read a few possible solutions for this and have tried the following with no luck:

- update the Flipper version
- I have patched the package [as per here](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/pull/138) - this is a continuation of the `rn-fetch-blob` package
- force the version of okttp to a later version (4.9.1)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Incidentally - the issue was because the header for the form post was being sent as `Content-Type=...` and `content-type=...` was expected :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I solve by adding this in the upload request headers.

```
Connection: 'close',
```

I guess it happens with the HTTP connection.At the beginning, i use fetch ,but it throw Network request failed.And after i use rn-fetch-blob ,it throw unexpected end of stream.